# Decomposition of interest rate risk

Tags: statistical-finance, multivariate

Hi I needed some clarification on something. I have three variables:

V1 which is an indicator of an interest rate risk premia

V2 which is an indicator of a credit risk premia

V3 which is an indicator of a liquidity risk premia.

While in theory the relationship of:

V1=V2+V3

should hold; I'm struggling to find a good modelling technique that can decompose V1 into subcomponents that relate to V2 and V3. I am searching for something beyond a vector auto-regressive model. My question is would State space modelling help me in this decomposition.

Comment: what theory can give you the relationship?